# How to preprocess view field?

Tags: views, theming, 8

I have view with one date field. Now I want to preprocess this date field(lets say I want to change the date format).

Twig file override : **views-view-field--field_date.html.twig**

Prepocess code I have tried but **kint** is showing me only **DEPTH TOO GREAT** value.

```
function my_sub_theme_preprocess_views_view_field__field_date(&$variables) {
    kint($variables['view']);
}
```

Please let me know how to preprocess this field. Is it possible to change date format in twig itself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The output of views field templates is flat markup. You can't change a render array like you can in field templates when rendering entities in view modes.

So if you want to change the output you have to start from scratch with the values that are in the database. In views field templates you can use the [getValue()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!views!src!Plugin!views!field!Field.php/function/Field%3A%3AgetValue/8.2.x) method from the field variable. As parameter you have to provide `row`:

```
{{ field.value(row) }}
```

The result is a single value or an array for multivalue fields.

### Example

**views-view-field--created.html.twig**

The raw value from `created` is a unix timestamp

```
Timestamp: {{ field.value(row) }}
```

You can use the timestamp for example to reformat the date with the date filter from twig:

```
Date: {{ field.value(row)|date("m/d/Y") }}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes. A date format can be changed from TWIG template itself. Look for more documentation on Date in Twig here - http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/filters/date.html

About **DEPTH TOO GREAT** of Twig. It's coming due to Kint having setting of less maxLevel than what is there in the variable you are trying to dump.

You can change DEPTH in same function itself by writing something like -

```
$_kintSettings['maxLevels'] = 10;
```